# Does it matter if subsets are open or closed to proof continuity?

Tags: general-topology

If $X$ and $Y$ are topological spaces, with $X_1$ and $X_2$ subsets of $X$ so that $X_1\cup X_2=X$, and if we know that $f|_{X_1}:X_1\to Y$ and $f|_{X_2}:X_2\to Y$ are continuous, is $f:X\to Y$ continuous?

Furthermore, does it matter whether $X_1$ and $X_2$ are open or closed?

Comment: It does matter, $X_1$ and $X_2$ need to be closed to guarantee that $f:X \to Y$ is continuous. If you work through the proof you will come to a point where you have to use that fact.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** Consider a function with a jump discontinuity.

For the second part, if  $x \in X_1$ or $x \in X_2$ and $X_1, X_2$ are open, use the fact that you can take an open set around $x$ which is contained in that $X_1,X_2$.

For closed, discuss separately the cases $x \in X_1 \cap X_2, x \in X_1 \backslash X_2$ and $x \in X_2 \backslash X_1$. The last two cases are almost identical to the open situation, and the first one is easy.

Comment: But doesn't this require $X_1$ and $X_2$ not to be disjoint? In which case it would work if they were both open, but not if they were both closed, right?

Comment: @Nicholas You are right, will fix it.

Comment: @Nicholas The OP doesn't state that $X_1\cap X_2\ne\emptyset$

Answer (score 0):

Consider $X=\mathbb{R}$ and $f(x)=0$ if $x\le 0$ and $f(x)=1$ if $x>0.$ With the Euclidean topology $f$ is not continuous. However $f|_{(-\infty,0]}$ and $f|_{(0,\infty)}$ are continuous and $\mathbb{R}=(-\infty,0]\cup (0,\infty).$ That is, if one set is open and the other is closed then the result doesn't hold.

Show that if they are open or closed then the result holds true.